# Sysprep Windows XP 64bit version

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, sysprep

Is there a sysprep client that will work windows xp 64bit? I couldn't find one and everything I tried just says that the program can't run on the machine or I have the wrong version of windows.

Thanks

Comment: There should be a copy of it in the Tools folder on the x64 install disc. It should be in the deploy.cab file, but a installed service pack may be what is wrong, trying to find the correct sysprep version at microsoft is near impossible for older os's...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577

Comment: Found sysprep for XP sp3, no mention if it will work for 64bit...http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11282#system-requirements

Comment: SP2....http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18976

Comment: Tried both the SP2 and SP3. I know 64bit only goes up to SP2 anyway. I'm not sure. I'll try checking on the disc.

Comment: @Moab so i was able to find the cd and get it from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a copy of it in the Tools folder on the x64 install disc. [It should be in the deploy.cab file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577).

Answer (score 4):

This is the [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8287) for the Windows Server 2003/XP x64 Sysprep.